# How to deploy (and run) a .NET Core ASP.NET application using VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to deploy (and run) a .NET Core ASP.NET application using VSTS. I would like to deploy to a local Linux machine (via an agent).

My build pipeline successfully creates the appropriate artefact (zip file) on the Linux machine but it really is not obvious to me how to configure the deploy pipeline to unzip the file, copy the files and dotnet run them.

All the examples I can find show how to deploy to the cloud, Docker, or locally to IIS on Windows, but not Linux.

There must be an easy way of achieving what seems to be a simple requirement?

Any pointers?!
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can this be the process you need?

### 1. Agent on linux

[image: On linux]

### 2. Unzip task

[image: Unzip task]

### 3. Dotnet run task

[image: dotnet run task]

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for! But I cannot find the dotnet run task. How do you select it?. Maybe I need new glasses but I can't find it?!

Comment: Arrgh! Just found it under Agent Phase. I was looking under Deployment Group phase! Thank you!